# Mysql issue on form insert

Tags: mysql

When I insert thing in my table via phpmyadmin I have no problem, but when I try to do it in the form I have created as  "admin-panel" in my site i get this message:

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db467610239`.`articulo`, CONSTRAINT `fk_articulo_genero` FOREIGN KEY (`genero_id`) REFERENCES `genero` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Thing is the number I insert into my new table already exists in my other table as they are linked as genre. I don't know why this is happening, i'm using exactly the same insert as in phpmyadmin just with some php tweaks:

```
INSERT INTO articulo VALUES (id= null   , nombre='$nombre', imagen='$imagen', text='$text', precio='$precio', popup='$popup', genero_id ='$genero_id')
```

Comment: Showing us some code might help. Maybe it's something in the PHP code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its a ID issue now, since i've checked all the values before inserting them in the database and they are all filled.

Maybe it has something to do with the auto ID increment from this main table? But that would be strange cause the error is saying its is in the foreign key?

Comment: Omit the `id= null , ` part.

Comment: i think you need to insert value first in table where genero_id is primary key then only you can insert value in table where genero_id is foreign key.Before inserting value in articulo table it db searches for exact genero_id in other table where it is a primary key and in case that genero_id is not found in that table db doesnot allow insert in articulo table

Comment: It says the first row doesn't match, and i think that's it because he is trying to fill the id with the second row value as im not using any id value in the first row...

Comment: @ntstha I'm just trying to re-use an already inserted value in the other table grabbing it as a FK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look more like this:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO articulo (
    nombre, imagen, text, precio, popup, genero_id
) VALUES (
    '$nombre', '$imagen', '$text', '$precio', '$popup', $genero_id
)";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '1' )' at line 4

Same message as if used mine... weird

Comment: That's most probably because `genero_id` is of type `int` or something. I updated my answer, but unless we know all the details we are just guessing.

Comment: It is yes because the value that i selected is 1, altho that value corresponds to the genero_id from the other table

Comment: See my updated answer: I changed `'$genero_id'` to `$genero_id` (without the `'`). EDIT: actually I had also forgotten a `'` before `$popup`. It is fixed now.

Comment: Fixed... your code worked! It was because it is an INT and if i add '' the database must think its not...

That was kind fo dumb by my part...

Σας ευχαριστούμε!

Comment: Always glad to help ! The `Σας ευχαριστούμε!` was nice :) And always remender: If any of the answers helped you solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.